# Unable to execute python exec inside aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, exec

I am trying to run a user-generated simple code (two sum) inside AWS lambda python runtime `Runtime.PYTHON_3_9`.

```py
def handler(event, context):
    a = {
        "code": "def twoSum(nums, target):\n    hash_map = {}\n\n    for i, num in enumerate(nums):\n        if target - num in hash_map:\n            return list(sorted([i, hash_map[target - num]]))\n        hash_map[num] = i\n\ndef solve():\r\n    testcases = [[[2, 7, 11, 15], 9]]\r\n    output = [[0, 1]]\r\n\r\n    total = len(testcases)\r\n    correct = 0\r\n\r\n    for i in range(len(testcases)):\r\n        result = twoSum(*testcases[i])\r\n\r\n        if result == output[i]:\r\n            correct += 1\r\n\r\n    print(correct, total)\r\n\r\n\r\nsolve()\r\n"
    }
    
    code = a["code"]
    print(code)
    exec(code)
```

This code prints

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
hash_map = {}
for i, num in enumerate(nums):
if target - num in hash_map:
return list(sorted([i, hash_map[target - num]]))
hash_map[num] = i
def solve():
testcases = [[[2, 7, 11, 15], 9]]
output = [[0, 1]]
total = len(testcases)
correct = 0
for i in range(len(testcases)):
result = twoSum(*testcases[i])
if result == output[i]:
correct += 1
print(correct, total)
solve()
```

while the actual code is

```py
def twoSum(nums, target):
    hash_map = {}

    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        if target - num in hash_map:
            return list(sorted([i, hash_map[target - num]]))
        hash_map[num] = i

def solve():
    testcases = [[[2, 7, 11, 15], 9]]
    output = [[0, 1]]

    total = len(testcases)
    correct = 0

    for i in range(len(testcases)):
        result = twoSum(*testcases[i])

        if result == output[i]:
            correct += 1

    print(correct, total)


solve()
```

All the spaces inside the exec strings are getting removed for some reason. Tried the same code on local Windows and macOS. It ran without any issues.

And this is the error I received

```
{
  "errorMessage": "name 'twoSum' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "requestId": "<some-request-id>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/python.py\", line 10, in handler\n    exec(code)\n",
    "  File \"<string>\", line 25, in <module>\n",
    "  File \"<string>\", line 17, in solve\n"
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this and make the exec work?

Comment: Might it just be the logging process that has removed the spaces? Alternatively, I wonder whether you can use `"""` ([Python multi-line string](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_multi_line_strings.asp)) to set the content, including line breaks?

Comment: You have a mix of `\n` and `\r\n` terminations. The latter appear to be working, in that the code does successfully invoke your `solve()` method.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein ok I'll try it. But if it was just an issue with the logging process, then the code should have run successfully.

Comment: **Side-note:** Be careful when running user-provided code. If the Lambda function has an IAM Role, then they could potentially do bad things to your AWS Account.

Comment: Yes, I understand. This is just a fun side project I am working on.